# Angular + Firebase: unable to register default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Angular and firebase push notifications

1. I Installed firebase package version 9.8.1 (latest)
2. Installed @angular/fire package version 7.3.0
3. added the manifest.json file in my src directory

   **manifest.json**:

   ```
   {
       "gcm_sender_id": "My-gcm-sender-id"
   }
   ```
4. Added my firebase-messaging-sw.js also in src directory:
   **firebase-messaging-sw.js**:

   ```
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js');
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
   firebase.initializeApp({
       apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
       authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
       projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
       storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx",
       messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
       appId: "xxxxxx",
       measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   });
   const messaging = firebase.messaging();
   ```
5. Added those two files in angular.json file:

   **angular.json**:

   ```
      "assets": [
                 "src/favicon.ico",
                 "src/assets",
                 "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js", 
                 "src/manifest.json" 
               ],
   ```
6. Updated my app.model.ts file:

   **app.model.ts**:

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   ...........

   import { AngularFireMessagingModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';
   import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from"@angular/fire/compat/database";
   import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
   import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
   import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
   import { MessagingService } from './services/messaging.service';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
             .....
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       HttpClientModule,
       AppRoutingModule,

       AngularFireDatabaseModule,
       AngularFireAuthModule,
       AngularFireMessagingModule,
       AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
   ....     
     ],
     providers: [xxx],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
7. added firebase credentials to my environment file.
8. made messagingService:

   **messaging.service.ts**:

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { AngularFireMessaging} from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';
   import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'

   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class MessagingService {
     x: any = null
     currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(this.x);

     constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging ) {

     }
     requestPermission() {
       this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
         (token) => {
           console.log(token);
         },
         (err) => {
           console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
         }
       );
     }
     receiveMessage() {
       this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
         (payload) => {
           console.log("new message received. ", payload);
           this.currentMessage.next(payload);
         })
     }
   }
   ```
9. added the messaging functionality to app.component:

   **app.component.ts**:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { MessagingService } from './services/messaging.service';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

     message: any;

     constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService){

     }
     ngOnInit(): void {
       this.messagingService.requestPermission()
       this.messagingService.receiveMessage()
       this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage
     }
     title = 'SFAeCommerce';
   }
   ```

When I run my project and allow notifications in Chrome, It's giving me this error:

```
firebase-messaging-sw.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js' failed to load.
    at http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:1
(anonymous) @ firebase-messaging-sw.js:1
messaging.service.ts:21 Unable to get permission to notify. FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
```

When I go to `https://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js`, It's returning the firebase-messaging-sw.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found the solution here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5732#issuecomment-969453902

From the version 9, if you want to keep using the `importScripts`, import the files adding 'compat' in the end of the file name, and you should good to go. Like:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
```

To use "9.8.1/firebase-app.js" (without 'compat'), for instance, it won't work with `importScripts`. The reason is because

> `importScripts` are ESMs which are only supported in browser context
> using `<script type="module">`

More explanation and the second way to import the files, just see the reference link above.

Answer (score 0):

For those who did the mistake which I did, double check your filename! It should be firebase-messag**ing**-sw.js instead of firebase-message-sw.js.

Thanks to @Gi Tavares, The web version 8 (namespaced) imports worked for me instead of web version 9.